# connection of computer at different places

Tags: networking, network-programming, neural-network

How can a connection be established b/w client computers and master computer and master computer should be connected through internet to my computer?
I want to conduct an online quiz in school in a manner such that all the computers at school are connected through localserver to master computer and master computer through internet to my computer to control the unwanted access. so,if it is possible how it can be done. or is there any book or something available regarding this stuff?

Comment: This is not a "neural network" question. :)  It is plausible that you can achieve what you want, but it depends greatly upon specific details of the existing network infrastructure... in this sense, it isn't really a problem involving 'network programming' - either.

Comment: can u please help me this part comes under which domain ??

Comment: Understanding the existing network infrastructure is "networking" - but information about this will be specific to your school - no-one on StackExchange can tell you this sort of information.  "network programming" is about writing software to communicate over specific network protocols, you don't have enough information to ask a question on this topic - i.e. you don't know what protocol(s) you need to use.  Finally, a 'neural-network' is a (mathematically intensive) branch of Artificial Intelligence that aims to model (biological) brain functions - completely unrelated to your question.